# Limit of a function as it approaches zero.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I was trying to verify a proof and there is a line that I am not sure how they came to the following conclusion.  They claim $$\lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{1}{x^n} e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=0$$ then $$\lim_{x \to 0} P(\frac{1}{x})e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=0$$
where $P(x)$ is a polynomial function.  My question how to prove the first statement.  My attempt was the following
$$\left|\frac{1}{x^n} e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}\right|\le\frac{1}{x^2} e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$ so let $$u=\frac{1}{x^2}$$ and $$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{u}{e^u}=0$$  Which implies that $$\left|\frac{1}{x^n} e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}\right|\le\frac{1}{x^2} e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}\le \epsilon$$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: No, your argument is wrong, as for $0<x<1$ , $0< x^n < x^2$, so $\frac{1}{x^n} > \frac{1}{x^2}$ and not the opposite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that

$$\ln\left( t^n e^{-t^2 } \right) = -t^2 + n \ln(t) $$

But $\ln(t) < t$, so

$$\ln\left( t^n e^{-t^2 } \right) \leq  -t^2 + nt $$

And this converge to $-\infty$ as $t\to +\infty$. This means that

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} t^n e^{-t^2 } =0$$

So you get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left| \frac{1}{x^n} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \right| = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{|x|^n} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} = \lim_{t\to +\infty}t^n e^{-t^2 } =0 $$